# Autoplay videos from google drive and alert when they finish JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

This is the code I use for autoplaying youtube videos:

```
var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '970',
          width: '100%',
          videoId: videos[index],
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {            
            location.reload();
        }
    }
```

And the html:

```
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
```

videos[index] - A variable in which all the videos are stored.

Is there any variation of the code that can play videos from google drive (or basically any code that can autoplay the video and alert when it's finished, it has to be in js)

I have looked for solutions to my problem for a few hours now and I tried them all out but without any success.

Does anyone have an idea on how I could accomplish this through JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO because `Google Drive` doesn't have an `API`, and it doesn't work like `Youtube`.